# "Identifier Expected" or "Invalid Prototype" when implementing a scripted constant in Inno Setup

Tags: function, syntax, inno-setup, pascalscript

So given this function, I get the error "Identifier Expected" on the `GetRoot := ROOTPage.Values[0];` line. I expect it is telling me that the `ROOTPage` is not defined?

```pascal
const
  DefaultRoot = 'C:\IAmGRoot';
Var
  ROOTPage : TInputQueryWizardPage;

procedure SetupRoot;
begin
  ROOTPage := CreateInputQueryPage(wpUserInfo,
    ExpandConstant('{cm:RootTitle}'), 
    ExpandConstant('{cm:RootInstructions}'),
    ExpandConstant('{cm:RootDescription}') + ' "' + DefaultRoot + '"'
    );
  
  ROOTPage.Add(ExpandConstant('{cm:SSRoot}') + ':', False);
  ROOTPage.Values[0] := ExpandConstant('{DefaultRoot}');

  // add SSROOT to path
end;

function GetRoot : string;
begin
  GetRoot := ROOTPage.Values[0];
end;
```

How should I interpret this error. What is an identifier in Pascal?

This [page](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Identifiers) tells me that identifiers are variable names. Perhaps I need to expand the `ROOTPage.Values[0]` in some way since I am referencing an array from an Inno Setup object?

Or maybe I need to return the value differently. I saw [one page](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Functions) on Pascal that said that you needed to avoid assigning to the function value on parameter less functions to avoid a recursive loop. Does this mean I should pass in a dummy value? or is there a different syntax? That page did not explain.

I secretly think my real issue is that I am not defining my function correctly... but well. That much compiles at least. **This question could become: How do you handle a parameter-less function in Pascal?**

I do not think Inno Setup is part of the issue, but I am working with Inno Setup in case that is important.

---

Update:
It doesn't seem to be the array because this gets the same error:

```pascal
const
  DefaultRoot = 'C:\IAmGRoot';

function GetRoot : string;
begin
  GetRoot := DefaultRoot;
end;
```

---

Update:
This [link](http://www.functionx.com/objectpascal/Lesson11.htm) has said that the function name can be replaced/ should be replaced with the key word `Result` such as the following code. I actually knew this, but the Inno Setup compiler does not recognize this as valid syntax. It then tells me my function is an invalid prototype.

```pascal
function GetRoot : string;
begin
  Result := DefaultRoot;
end;
```

---

Update:
If I do this I get "Invalid Prototype for GetRoot"

```pascal
function GetRoot : boolean;
begin
  Result := False;
end;
```

---

Update for @Martin Prikryl:

Well I use it a few places but the typical use would be like this:

```
[Files]
Source: "C:\ValidPath\Release\*"; DestDir: "{app}\bin"; Components: DefinedComponent
Source: "C:\ValidPath\Deployment\*"; DestDir: "{code:GetRoot}\"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs; Components: DefinedComponent
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Identifier expected

Your code would be correct in a Pascal, but it does not compile in Pascal Script.

In Pascal, when you want to assign a return value of a function, you either assign the value to a "variable" with a name of the function or to `Result` variable.

So this is correct:

```pascal
function GetRoot: string;
begin
  GetRoot := ROOTPage.Values[0];
end;
```

And this too (both are equivalent):

```pascal
function GetRoot: string;
begin
  Result := ROOTPage.Values[0];
end;
```

In the Pascal Script, only the `Result` works. When you use the name of the function, you get the *"Identifier expected."*

---

### Invalid prototype

You get this when the function is called from outside of the `Code` section and a specific parameter list/return value is required. But you didn't tell us, what you use the `GetRoot` function for.

There are two places, where you can use a custom function in Inno Setup:

- [`Check` parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptcheck): For this the function must return a `Boolean` and take either no parameter or one parameter (the parameter type is determined by a value you provide in the `Check` parameter).

  ```pascal
  function MyProgCheck(): Boolean;

  function MyDirCheck(DirName: String): Boolean;
  ```
- [Scripted Constants](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptconstants): The function must return a `string` and take one `string` parameter, even if no parameter is provided in the scripted constant. I assume this is your use case. If you do not need any parameter, just declare it, but do not use it:

  ```pascal
  function GetRoot(Param: String): string;
  begin
    Result := ROOTPage.Values[0];
  end;
  ```

Comment: Slapping forehead now. I knew that. Excellent. It now builds. SuperDuper.