# What does the "if" statement mean in Inno Setup Pascal Script

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

```pascal
if x <> '' then begin
    Result := True;
end else 
begin
    Result := False;
end;
```

For when the `if` statement will be executed?

Answer (score 2):

Basic constructs like this behave in Pascal Script the same as in Pascal.

[Free Pascal documentation for `If..then..else` statement](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refsu57.html) says:

> The expression between the `if` and `then` keywords must have a `Boolean` result type. If the expression evaluates to `True` then the statement following the `then` keyword is executed.
>
> If the expression evaluates to `False`, then the statement following the `else` keyword is executed, if it is present.

---

The expression `x <> ''` means: the (string) variable `x` [not equals](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refsu50.html) an empty string.

---

So overall, the code does: If `x` is not an empty string, set `Result` to `True`, else set `Result` to `False`. Note that [`Result` is a special identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33656548/850848#33659094) used to set a return value of a function in which it is used.

---

Actually, the code can be simplified to a single statement:

```pascal
Result := (x <> '');
```

*(brackets are for readability only, they are not required)*