# InnoSetup, How to open a port given by the user in the Wizard?

Tags: inno-setup, wizard, windows-firewall

In a innosetup installer, my goal is to configure the Windows firewall to open the adequate port for my software

```
[Run]
Filename: "{sys}\netsh.exe"; Parameters: "firewall set portopening protocol=TCP port=""{code:GetServerPort()}"" name=NxTCP mode=ENABLE"; StatusMsg: "Opening TCP Port ""{code:GetServerPort()}"; Flags: runhidden

[Code]
function GetServerPort(): String;
begin
  Result := "5555"; //obtained with the Wizard
end;
```

And I get this error

> Required function or procedure 'GetServerPort()' not found.

Or if I drop the `()` at the call

> Invalid prototype for 'GetServerPort'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code works for me:

```
[Run]
Filename: "{sys}\netsh.exe"; Parameters: "firewall set portopening protocol=TCP port=""{code:GetServerPort}"" name=NxTCP mode=ENABLE"; StatusMsg: "Opening TCP Port ""{code:GetServerPort}"; Flags: runhidden


[Code]
function GetServerPort(Value: string): String;
begin
  Result := '5555'; //obtained with the Wizard
end;
```

Your function call in the `[Run]` is not properly formatted.  The `{code:XXX}` is basically a `Check` parameter and is documented at http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptcheck.htm

Comment: So it was all a question of signature? Adding a mystical `Value: String` goes.

Comment: `{code:XXX}` is not a `Check` parameter. `Check` parameter actually does not require the `string` argument, while `{code}` does. See [“Identifier Expected” or “Invalid Prototype” when implementing a scripted constant in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33656548/850848).