# Inno Setup - Use Input from [Code] to as a parameter after setup of [Files]

Tags: inno-setup

I have a piece of the script to get location of Python Home. The [Code] section is as follows -

```
; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!
#define code
#define MyAppName "API DAST"
#define MyAppVersion "0.1"
#define MyAppPublisher "Prateek Inc."
#define MyAppURL "https://prateek.com"

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application. Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{5547FBEE-AA97-4224-AF61-36C9F720270C}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
DefaultDirName={autopf}\API_DAST
DisableDirPage=yes
DefaultGroupName={#MyAppName}
AllowNoIcons=yes
; Uncomment the following line to run in non administrative install mode (install for current user only.)
;PrivilegesRequired=lowest
OutputDir=mysetupcompiler
OutputBaseFilename=mysetup
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes
WizardStyle=modern

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Files]
Source: "C:\Users\pnarendr\Desktop\API_DAST\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files
; TODO: Change a few config files by running a Python Script. But first, get Python Home from input
Source: "C:\Users\pnarendr\Desktop\output.log"; DestDir: "{code:GetPythonHome}";


[Code]
var
  OutputProgressWizardPage: TOutputProgressWizardPage;
  OutputProgressWizardPageAfterID: Integer;

procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  //InputQueryWizardPage: TInputQueryWizardPage;
  //InputOptionWizardPage: TInputOptionWizardPage;
  InputDirWizardPage: TInputDirWizardPage;
  PrimaryServerPage: TInputQueryWizardPage;
  InputFileWizardPage: TInputFileWizardPage;
  OutputMsgWizardPage: TOutputMsgWizardPage;
  OutputMsgMemoWizardPage: TOutputMsgMemoWizardPage;
  AfterID: Integer;
  PythonHome: String;
begin
  //WizardForm.PasswordEdit.Text := '{#Password}';

  AfterID := wpSelectTasks;

  //AfterID := CreateCustomPage(AfterID, 'CreateCustomPage', 'ADescription').ID;

  //InputQueryWizardPage := CreateInputQueryPage(AfterID, 'CreateInputQueryPage', 'ADescription', 'ASubCaption');
  //InputQueryWizardPage.Add('&APrompt:', False);
  //AfterID := InputQueryWizardPage.ID;

  //InputOptionWizardPage := CreateInputOptionPage(AfterID, 'CreateInputOptionPage', 'ADescription', 'ASubCaption', False, False);
  //InputOptionWizardPage.Add('&AOption');
  //AfterID := InputOptionWizardPage.ID;

  InputDirWizardPage := CreateInputDirPage(AfterID, 'Choose Python Home Folder', '', '', False, '');
  InputDirWizardPage.Add('&Location of Python Home:');
  InputDirWizardPage.Values[0] := 'C:\Python27'; //Default Value
  AfterID := InputDirWizardPage.ID;


  InputFileWizardPage := CreateInputFilePage(AfterID, 'CreateInputFilePage', 'ADescription', 'ASubCaption');
  InputFileWizardPage.Add('&APrompt:', 'Executable files|*.exe|All files|*.*', '.exe');
  //Will this get latest value even if you go back???
  PythonHome := InputDirWizardPage.Values[0]; 
  Log('Python Home - '+PythonHome);
  AfterID := InputFileWizardPage.ID;

  OutputMsgWizardPage := CreateOutputMsgPage(AfterID, 'CreateOutputMsgPage', 'ADescription', 'AMsg');
  AfterID := OutputMsgWizardPage.ID;

  OutputMsgMemoWizardPage := CreateOutputMsgMemoPage(AfterID, 'CreateOutputMsgMemoPage', 'ADescription', 'ASubCaption', 'AMsg');
  AfterID := OutputMsgMemoWizardPage.ID;

  OutputProgressWizardPage := CreateOutputProgressPage('CreateOutputProgressPage', 'ADescription');
  OutputProgressWizardPageAfterID := AfterID;
end;

function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
var
  Position, Max: Integer;
begin
  if CurPageID = OutputProgressWizardPageAfterID then begin
    try
      Max := 25;
      for Position := 0 to Max do begin
        OutputProgressWizardPage.SetProgress(Position, Max);
        if Position = 0 then
          OutputProgressWizardPage.Show;
        Sleep(2000 div Max);
      end;
    finally
      OutputProgressWizardPage.Hide;
    end;
  end;
  Result := True;
end;

function PrepareToInstall(var NeedsRestart: Boolean): String;
begin
  if SuppressibleMsgBox('Do you want to stop Setup at the Preparing To Install wizard page?', mbConfirmation, MB_YESNO, IDNO) = IDYES then
    Result := 'Stopped by user';
end;

function GetPythonHome(Param: String): string;
begin
  Result := 'C:\Python27'; //Use default
end;
```

I don't know how to take `InputDirWizardPage.Values[0]` as input to run a Python script after setup (to change a config file in the folder copied). How do I do it ?

The Invalid Identifier exception was taken care . Apparently Pascal Script isnt the same as Pascal

Comment: The "problem" is that you didn't copy the code as it is. Anyway, see the second duplicate question.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl how can you say that? What is wrong?

Comment: Did you follow the other link, I've posted?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl is there a manual for Inno Setup  scripting ?

Comment: Stop asking duplicate questions and read the answer I've linked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33659094/850848 -- It even links to Inno Setup documentation you are asking for.

Comment: It has nothing to do with Pascal vs. Pascal Script. --- You are implementing an interface, so you need to conform to its prototype.