# Generating application arguments for Run section in scripted constant based on state of checkboxes and radio buttons on Finished page of Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I want to modify the parameters of a `FileName` in the `[Run]` section according to the state of some radio and check buttons.  In my code section I have added:

```pascal
function GetParameterString:String;
var
  I: Integer;
  s1, s2: String;
begin
  for I := 0 to WizardForm.RunList.Items.Count - 1 do
    if (wizardform.runlist.items.checked[i] = true) then begin
      if (wizardform.runlist.items.itemcaption[i] = 'View Whats''s New in ' + {#MyAppVersion}) then       
        s1 := GetShellFolderByCSIDL(CSIDL_APPDATA, True) + '\Positron Studio\What''s New.pdf';
      if (wizardform.runlist.items.itemcaption[i] = 'Positron Studio Dark' then
        s2 := '-d'
      else if (wizardform.runlist.Items.itemcaption[i] = 'Positron Studio Light' then
        s2 := '-l'
    end;
  end;
  Result := s1 + s2
end;
```

and I am calling it from the `[Run]` section like this:

```
FileName:"{app}\{#MyAppExename}"; parameters: Code: GetParameterString; \
    Flags: postinstall nowait
```

It fails on the `wizardform.runlist.items.checked[i] = true` with:

> Unknown Identifier Checked

How do I get the `Checked` value of a checkbox or radiobutton?

Answer (score 1):

Lookup [Pascal Scripting: Scripted Constants](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptconstants) where it states:

> The Pascal script can contain several functions which are called when Setup wants to know the value of a scripted `{code:...}` constant. The called function must have 1 `String` parameter named `Param`, and must return a `String` or a `Boolean` value depending on where the constant is used.

So try:

```
FileName: "{app}\{#MyAppExename}"; Parameters: {code:GetParameterString}; Flags: postinstall nowait
```

The above has not been tested. It may not fix the underlaying issue with what you are actually doing in the `GetParameterString` method.

Comment: The compile fails because the Checked state is not recognised.  I am obviously not accessing the controls correctly so I need guidance on that.  My routine returns a string so as far as I can see there is not a problem in the FileName entry in the [run] section

Comment: Thank you that was very helpful.  Is possible for the preprocessor defines to be used by the code section? and is it possible to tell if an item in the runlist is radiobutton or Checkbutton?

Comment: @JohnBarrat No, you cannot tell if an item of `TNewCheckListBox` is radio button or a checkbox. The list defined by the `Run` section cannot even contain radio buttons. If you have hacked it somehow in the code, you know the indexes of the checkboxes and radio buttons anyway, don't you?

Comment: I think my best approach would be to replace the normal run page with a custom page. It has other benefits in doing this as I can add images images.

Comment: @JohnBarrat Sure. But the whole point of StackOverflow is that if people take the time to supply you answers and you find them useful that you "upvote" them.

Answer (score 1):

Your immediate problem is that there's indeed no `wizardform.runlist.items.checked` (nor `wizardform.runlist.items.itemcaption`).

You want `WizardForm.RunList.Checked` (and `WizardForm.RunList.ItemCaption`).

See the [`TNewCheckListBox` documentation](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TNewCheckListBox).

---

Your next problem will be the invalid syntax of the reference to your [scripted constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptconstants) in the `Parameters` parameter (as Andrew has already shown in his answer). It should be:

```
Parameters: {code:GetParameterString};
```

---

Your next problem will be *"Invalid prototype"*:
["Identifier Expected" or "Invalid Prototype" when implementing a scripted constant in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33656548/850848)

It should be:

```pascal
function GetParameterString(Param: string): string;
```

---

Depending on how you application handles the argument, you also might need to quote the path to the .pdf, as there are spaces in it.

It also bit strange, how you add the `-d` and `-l` to the path. Did you really intend to pass something like this to the application?

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Positron Studio\What's New.pdf-d
```

---

*It also bit unclear to me, how are you combining multiple "run list" entries states into arguments of one particular entry. But I assume you know what you are doing.*